# reduce KafkaProducer send async response time

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-producer-api

My Java KafkaProducer is able to send messages and able to get async call back in both success/failure cases properly.
Whenever there is a failure, in Callback, I get "Failed to update metadata after 60000 ms".
i.e for each error case, I need to wait for 6000 ms i.e 6 seconds.
How can I reduce the callback response time? Is it configurable and can set in Producer Properties? 
Then which property key I have to use to reduce the time from 6000 ms to some thing less than that.
I have tried max.timeout.ms and request.timeout.ms set to 3000 (both as string or integer. But it didn't reflect.

Answer (score 0):

`Failed to update metadata after 60000 ms` means the client cannot retrieve the metadata from the broker(s) within the specified time. If you want to reduce this timeout, producer configuration `max.block.ms` could be set to a lower value.